# ¿Cómo poner un Sticker al hacer foto en Android?

Tags: java, android

Me gustaría saber qué puedo hacer para que en mi aplicación, cuando se llama a la cámara del dispositivo, a la vez que se vea la imagen de la cámara para tomar la foto, se vea superpuesta otra imagen propia a modo de pegatina o marco para la foto; y que al tomar la foto se guarden las dos imágenes juntas, la captura de la cámara con la imagen superpuesta.

Para hacer una foto utilizo el siguiente método tras el evento de un botón:

```java
boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         String file = ruta_fotos + nombreFoto + ".jpg";
         File mi_foto = new File( file );
         try {
             mi_foto.createNewFile();
         } catch (IOException ex) {              
             Log.e("ERROR ", "Error:" + ex);
         }       
         //
         Uri uri = Uri.fromFile( mi_foto );
         //Abre la camara para tomar la foto
         Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
         //Guarda imagen
         cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
         //Retorna a la actividad
         startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 0);
     }

 });
```

Comment: Esto sería usar realidad aumentada dentro de tu aplicación

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/95574/how-to-add-a-logo-to-a-captured-image

Comment: Ray, trata con Realidad aumentada y pregunta si surgen dudas.

Comment: ¿Pudiste resolver este problema? me gustaria que pudieras apoyarme, ya que tengo una duda similar. Gracias

Comment: @Leo [Aquí.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/112099/colocar-sticker-a-imagen-android)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es colocar un ImageView en el layout que despliegas el preview de la cámara, como `src` del Imageview pon la imagen o marco deseado (la imagen debe ser semi transparente para que te permita ver la vista de la cámara).
Una vez que obtuviste la fotografía con un canvas puedes unir las dos imágenes

Answer (score 0):

Usa [CameraView](https://github.com/natario1/CameraView) Te permite poner overlay, tu overlay sera una view que pases como hija de cameraview.